# UIView's designated initializers in swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I've subclassed `UIView` like so

```
class CustomView: UIView {
}
```

And I could do something like

```
let customView = CustomView()
```

But when I override what I believe are the two designated initialisers for `UIView` i.e. `init(frame:)` and `init(coder:)` like so

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

I can no longer create the view like so as it complains that `init()` no longer exists

```
let customView = CustomView()
```

My understanding is that If I override all the designated initialisers, I should inherit all the convenience initializers as well.

So my question is. Is `init()` not a convenience initializer on UIView? Or is there another designated initializer on UIView that I haven't overrided yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`init` is not a convenience initializer on UIView. `init` is not an initializer on UIView at all! It is an initializer on its superclass NSObject - UIView merely inherits it. And it is a *designated* initializer on NSObject. So when you implemented a designated initializer, you cut off inheritance of designated initializers - including `init`.

Comment: See my discussion of this "surprise" here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_class_initializers

Comment: i see. The fact that `init()` delegates to `init(frame:)` in `UIView`, doesn't this mean that it cannot be a designated initializer?

Comment: Objective-C is not Swift! The Cocoa APIs are written in Objective-C, and existed for decades before Swift did; they break _all_ sorts of "rules" that the Swift compiler would not let _you_ break. Objective-C initializers call each other in all sorts of surprising ways. Again, read the discussion on "surprises" that I pointed you to in my previous comment.